# Como criar linha de soma no final de tabela

Tags: php, html, mysql, table

Tenho uma página com uma tabela que mostra informações da quantidade de itens previstos pra serem realizados e a quantidade de itens que realmente foram realizados no final de cada mês.

Se a quantidade de itens previstos for maior que a de itens realizados a célula fica vermelha, caso contrário, fica verde.

Gostaria de fazer no final dessa tabela um linha que mostrasse o total de valores de cada coluna, como se fosse um registro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Esse é o código da tabela:

```
<?php

                            require 'conn.php';

                            //Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
                            $qry = mysqli_query($lnk, "select * from qualite");

                            //Pegando os nomes dos campos
                            $num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

                            for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
                                $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
                            }

                            //Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
                            $table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse"> <tr style="">';

                            for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
                                $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
                            }

                            //Montando o corpo da tabela
                            //Tá meio gambiarrado mas pelo menos funciona.
                            $table .= '<tbody>';
                            while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
                                $table .= '<tr>';
                                if($r['ID'] > $r['ID']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['ID'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['ID'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['KPI'] > $r['KPI']){
                                  $table .= '<td style="font-weight:bolder;">'.$r['KPI'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td style="font-weight:bolder;">'.$r['KPI'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['PILOTE'] > $r['PILOTE']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['PILOTE'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['PILOTE'].'</td>';
                                }

                                //Aqui começam os meses
                                if($r['JAN_PREV'] > $r['JAN_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['JAN_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['JAN_REAL'].'</td>';
                                  $jan_prev .=+ $r['JAN_PREV'];
                                  $jan_real .=+ $r['JAN_REAL'];
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['JAN_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['JAN_REAL'].'</td>';
                                  $jan_prev .=+ $r['JAN_PREV'];
                                  $jan_real .=+ $r['JAN_REAL'];
                                }
                                if($r['FEV_PREV'] > $r['FEV_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['FEV_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['FEV_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['FEV_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['FEV_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['MAR_PREV'] > $r['MAR_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['MAR_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['MAR_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['MAR_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['MAR_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['ABR_PREV'] > $r['ABR_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['ABR_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['ABR_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['ABR_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['ABR_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['MAI_PREV'] > $r['MAI_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['MAI_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['MAI_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['MAI_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['MAI_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['JUN_PREV'] > $r['JUN_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['JUN_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['JUN_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['JUN_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['JUN_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['JUL_PREV'] > $r['JUL_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['JUL_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['JUL_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['JUL_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['JUL_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['AGO_PREV'] > $r['AGO_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['AGO_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['AGO_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['AGO_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['AGO_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['SET_PREV'] > $r['SET_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['SET_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['SET_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['SET_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['SET_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['OUT_PREV'] > $r['OUT_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['OUT_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['OUT_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['OUT_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['OUT_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['NOV_PREV'] > $r['NOV_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['NOV_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['NOV_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['NOV_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['NOV_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }
                                if($r['DEZ_PREV'] > $r['DEZ_REAL']){
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['DEZ_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:red;">'.$r['DEZ_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                  $table .= '<td>'.$r['DEZ_PREV'].'</td>';
                                  $table .= '<td style="background:green;">'.$r['DEZ_REAL'].'</td>';
                                }



                                // Adicionando botão de edição

                                $table .= '<td><form action="qualite-edicao.php" method="post">'; 
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="KPI" value="'.$r['KPI'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="PILOTE" value="'.$r['PILOTE'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="'.$r['JAN_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="'.$r['JAN_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV PREV" value="'.$r['FEV_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV REAL" value="'.$r['FEV_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR PREV" value="'.$r['MAR_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR REAL" value="'.$r['MAR_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR PREV" value="'.$r['ABR_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR REAL" value="'.$r['ABR_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI PREV" value="'.$r['MAI_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI REAL" value="'.$r['MAI_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN PREV" value="'.$r['JUN_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN REAL" value="'.$r['JUN_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL PREV" value="'.$r['JUL_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL REAL" value="'.$r['JUL_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO PREV" value="'.$r['AGO_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO REAL" value="'.$r['AGO_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET PREV" value="'.$r['SET_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET REAL" value="'.$r['SET_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT PREV" value="'.$r['OUT_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT REAL" value="'.$r['OUT_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV PREV" value="'.$r['NOV_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV REAL" value="'.$r['NOV_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="'.$r['DEZ_PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="'.$r['DEZ_REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></i> Editar </i></button>'; //
                                $table .= '</form></td>';



                                //MODAL COM OS GRÁFICOS
                                $table .= '<td><form action="graf-qualite.php" method="post">'; 
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="KPI" value="'.$r['KPI'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="PILOTE" value="'.$r['PILOTE'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN PREV" value="'.$r['JAN PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JAN REAL" value="'.$r['JAN REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV PREV" value="'.$r['FEV PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="FEV REAL" value="'.$r['FEV REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR PREV" value="'.$r['MAR PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAR REAL" value="'.$r['MAR REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR PREV" value="'.$r['ABR PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ABR REAL" value="'.$r['ABR REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI PREV" value="'.$r['MAI PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="MAI REAL" value="'.$r['MAI REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN PREV" value="'.$r['JUN PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUN REAL" value="'.$r['JUN REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL PREV" value="'.$r['JUL PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="JUL REAL" value="'.$r['JUL REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO PREV" value="'.$r['AGO PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="AGO REAL" value="'.$r['AGO REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET PREV" value="'.$r['SET PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="SET REAL" value="'.$r['SET REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT PREV" value="'.$r['OUT PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="OUT REAL" value="'.$r['OUT REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV PREV" value="'.$r['NOV PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="NOV REAL" value="'.$r['NOV REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ PREV" value="'.$r['DEZ PREV'].'">';
                                $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="DEZ REAL" value="'.$r['DEZ REAL'].'">';
                                $table .= '<!-- Button -->
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" name="button" onclick="abreModal(' . $r['ID'] .');">
                                              Gráfico
                                            </button>

                                            <!-- Modal -->

                                            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" onload="click("button");">
                                              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Gráfico</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>'; //
                                $table .= '</form></td>';

                            }

                            //AQUI É ONDE DEVERIA FICAR A SOMA 
                            $table .= '<tr>
                                          <td></td>
                                          <td>Total</td>
                                          <td></td>
                                          <td>Soma Jan_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Jan_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Fev_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Fev_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Mar_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Mar_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Abr_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Abr_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Mai_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Mai_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Jun_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Jun_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Jul_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Jul_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Ago_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Ago_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Set_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Set_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Out_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Out_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Nov_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Nov_Real</td>
                                          <td>Soma Dez_Prev</td>
                                          <td>Soma Dez_Real</td>
                                      </tr>';

                            //Finalizando a tabela
                            $table .= '</tbody></table>';


                            //Imprimindo a tabela
                            echo '<div class="table-table" style="overflow-x:auto;">';
                            echo $table;
                    ?>
```

Eu fiz a linha meio manualmente aí pra exemplificar, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer pra somar os valores. Alguém pode me ajudar?

**TESTE 1:**
Tentei fazer a soma dentro dos `ifs` que printam a tabela, mas deu um resultado que com certeza não tá certo. Coloquei no código acima as alterações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mariana, você pode fazer a soma usando o while do corpo da tabela, usando uma variável para ir acumulando os totais

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, o problema era muito simples.

Fazendo isso eu estava concatenando e não somando.

```
$jan_prev .=+ $r['JAN_PREV'];
```

Alterei para isso e deu certo.

```
$jan_prev =+ $r['JAN_PREV'];
```

Answer (score 2):

User uma variável dentro do laço while para ir armazenando os valores, lembre-se de utilizar o operador += para não perder os ultimos valores, no final escreva esta variavel nos campos que você deseja

Comment: Então, deu ruim. Vou editar com o resultado.